# Read request body two times in Golang

Tags: json, go, request

```
type ValidationModel struct {
    Name     string `json:"name" valid:"alpha,required~Name is required"`
    Email    string `json:"email" valid:"email~Enter a valid email.,required~Email is required."`
    Password string `json:"password" valid:"required~Password is required"`
}

validationModel := ValidationModel{}

json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&validationModel)

_, err := govalidator.ValidateStruct(validationModel)
```

First I am validating the request body using govalidator.

```
type UserModel struct {
    ID           bson.ObjectId `json:"_id" bson:"_id"`
    Name         string        `json:"name" bson:"name"`
    Email        string        `json:"email" bson:"email"`
    Password     string        `json:"password,omitempty" bson:"-"`
    PasswordHash string        `json:"-" bson:"passwordHash"`
    Salt         string        `json:"-" bson:"salt"`
    Token        string        `json:"token,omitempty" bson:"-"`
}


user := models.UserModel{}
json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&user)

fmt.Println(user)
```

And after validating the request, again I am decoding the request body into user struct, but the request body has been read once using validationModel, so when I try to again decode it into user, it is not giving me any values.

I can think of two solutions here:

1. Store request body in one separate variable, and use that variable two times.
2. Copy validationModel values in user.

But I don't have any idea about to implement these approaches and which approach is best to follow. Or is there any other solution which can be implemented?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your case, you should re-factor to not read the body twice. It would be far more efficient (especially if you have large bodies), to validate the decoded data _after_ you have decoded it, rather than decoding twice.

Comment: @Flimzy Can you please explain how can I refactor the code? I have another approach as well in which I can copy data of one struct into another. How can I do that?

Comment: In general:  Don't have a separate 'ValidationModel'--instead, validate the `UserModel`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Storing the data can be easily done with [ioutil.ReadAll()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll):

```
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

If you need the `data` back as a `io.Reader` (which is how the `r.Body` is), then you can use [bytes.NewReader()](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader):

```
reader := bytes.NewReader(data)
```

And ACTUALLY, `r.Body` is a `io.ReadCloser`, so if you need that you can use [ioutil.NopCloser()](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#NopCloser) in conjunction with [bytes.NewReader()](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#NewReader):

```
reader := ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(data))
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use ioutil.ReadAll when r.Body is very large, such as 1G Bytes.

Comment: This is true, however you can protect yourself with a https://golang.org/pkg/io/#LimitedReader